# Use classification model for object detection framework

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm currently trying to use the [Object Detection framework](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) from Google Tensorflow.
I have a trained model for something similar to MNIST. What is the easiest way to use this as the classification checkpoint?
As I currently understand it I can use a classification or an object detection checkpoint. 
Just don't know how to use my classification checkpoint as I think the structure of the network is specified by the type in

```
 feature_extractor {
  type: "ssd_mobilenet_v2"
  ...
```

Do I have to provide my own model type using [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/defining_your_own_model.md)?

All of the pretrained models have a lot of layers and my MNIST like dataset has only 3 which was quite easy to train.

The goal in general is to detect math symbols on a white background with bounding boxes. The classification part was easy but trying to extend it by object detection seems to hard. Using pretrained models for object detection which were trained on real world images seem to be better than scratch but pretty bad in general.

Any ideas appreciated!